# When should I use: me or to me?

Tags: collocations, prepositional-phrases, direct-objects, indirect-objects

Sometimes I am confused in the correct way of using ***me*** or ***to me***. Example, *answer me* or *answer to me*; *love me* or *love to me*. Could you help me to differentiate each one?

Comment: I’m going to migrate your question to our sister site for [ell.se] because I realize that this can seem trickier to a native speaker of Spanish (as by your name I take you to be) than monoglot Anglophones who know no Spanish might at first guess it to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some verbs take "to" as preposition. It depends on the position of direct and indirect object in the sentence:

For example:

> Give me the book.

"the book" is the direct object of "give", and "me" is the indirect object. If you change their position, you need "to" before "me" (indirect object):

> Give the book **to me**.

The structure is:

> 'subject' +'verb' + 'direct object' + preposition + 'indirect object'

However, "answer" takes one direct object

> Answer the question

If "answer" is used as "noun" it can take "to" as preposition

> It is the answer to the question 4
>
> These are important questions and we want answers to them

Answer (score 6):

"Answer me" means "give me an answer" (or "say something".)

"Answer **to** me" is quite different, and means "Report [answer] to me and no one else":

> Remember: you answer to me and no one else.

"Love me" means exactly what it says -- "Show me affection."

On its own, "love to me" is ungrammatical. However, you can use it in a sentence as @wintersoldier suggests:

> Make love to me.

Comment: @RafaelAndresOteroAvila crystal

Comment: @Mick isn't there a usage called " make love to me " which means to have physical relationship.

Comment: @wintersolider That's true enough.